# Performing a calculation on selected cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

In excel, can I select cells in a random fashion using the CTRL key and a left click on the mouse and then have the sum of those cells placed in another cell?

Typically, I select a sequence of cells, like a1-a5 and press autosum and it puts the sum in a6, or a1-e1 and it puts the sum in f6. These cells are seqeuential in nature.

Instead of sitting on a6 and writing the formula a1+a2+a3+a4+a5.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In the cell you want the results, type `=SUM(`, then use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and left click to select the cells you want to SUM. Excel will add the commas.

When done, type the closing `)` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but each cell needs to be comma separated. So your formula will look like this in the end `=SUM(A1,B2,C3)`

- Select the cell where you want to display the sum.
- Type `=SUM(`
- Now click a cell you want to SUM, add a comma, click the next cell, add a comma, and so on...
- Type `)` to complete the formula.

### Edit:

CharlieRB is right, Excel will automatically add the commas. So just click the cells you want to SUM.